# Why is exit status -11 returned?

Tags: python, c, testing, scripting, subprocess

I'm writing a python script to check a C program I made. Sometimes, when calling my executable from the script, I get

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command Command '['./parallel_snake', 'input/input1', 'output/output1', '20000']' returned non-zero exit status -11
```

This is the line where I call the executable:

```
p = subprocess.check_output(["./parallel_snake", "input/" + input_file, "output/" + input_file.replace("in", "out"), "20000"])
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I get rid of it?

EDIT My code:

```
input_files = [f for f in listdir("input")]
num_threads = [2, 4, 6, 8]

for input_file in input_files:
    print "Checking " + input_file + "\n"
    for num in num_threads:
        os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = str(num)
        p = subprocess.check_output(["./parallel_snake", "input/" + input_file, "output/" + input_file.replace("in", "out"), "20000"])
        print "\t" + str(num) + " threads: " + str(p)
```

Input for the parallel_snake C program:

```
3 // there are 3 snakes 
1 2 1 N // head of a snake (1, 2)/its encoding (1)/its move direction (N) 
5 7 2 E // second snake 
3 4 3 S // third snake 
9 9 // dimensions of the map 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 3 3 3 3 0 
0 1 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 // the map with the 3 snakes 
The purpose is to move the snakes in the indicated direction as long as they do not collide. As you can see, if snake 1 goes up and 2 goes to right, they will collide in 5 steps
I used #pragma omp parallel for to count from 0 to the maximum number of movements, which was 20 000. If I decide to not paralelise the counting, but to paralelise the iteration through the snakes (i have an array of them), the problem does not appear.
```

Comment: Maybe your C program is returning with an exit status of -11?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I do not think so, because I have no problem when I execute it simply in the command line.

Comment: The process didn't even run. Something like `fork()` failed with `-EAGAIN`.

Comment: I have to mention that I use OMP. Can that be a problem?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - If so, wouldn't Python indicate it as such?  (Presumably behind the scenes, it can tell the difference between a `fork` failure and the return value of `waitpid` or similar.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Sure, if `subprocess` was written to handle it properly. It's probably such a rare case that it was just never accounted for.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Perhaps.  But I'd place my bets on the bug being in the OP's code (which isn't shown) rather than in the Python interpreter/library ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I never claimed it was a bug; it could be something like hitting the process limit for the system/user.

Comment: I added my code guys, you can look at it if you want

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - At the risk of going off on a tangent - if Python is misinterpreting the return value of `fork` as the exit status of a process, I'd call that a bug :)

Comment: @VladIordache - Can you construct a [minimal test-case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the C code that triggers this issue?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes I can, but I can not show you the C code because of confidentiality issues. That is part of a homework at college. Do you still think a test case would help?

Comment: It's good debugging practice to reduce the problem to a minimal test case, so I'd say yes :)

Comment: You can check the test case in the edited question, sorry it took so long

Comment: `Command Command`? That's curious. What platform is this?

Comment: ...I'd actually be tempted to pull out `sysdig` or `strace` and see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: BTW, what happens if instead of `parallel_snake` you use, say, `['sleep', '1']` -- a program that everyone has? Which is to say, can you generate a reproducer that *doesn't* require any content from your coursework to generate the same bug?

Comment: With sleep 1 there is no problem